# I'm creating an array of DOM elems and am selecting a img tag, then a series of p tags, how can I get innerHTML of the p's and src link from the img?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, dom, domdocument

This is how I'm creating the array:  `const textData = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.product-image, .product-detail > p'))`

The array contents are an img tag followed by a amount of p tags and depending on how many items are on the page, more img tags followed by more p tags, I would like to map or loop through the elements and based on what tag the element is, replace it in the array with its innerHTML(for the p tag) or its src link(img tag). How can I achieve this in node? I cant figure out how to loop through and determine the tag type and preform the specified operation.

Comment: What is the purpose of selector `a.non-returnable` ?

Comment: that can be ignored sorry. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a map and tagNAme

```
textData.map((element) => {
  if (element.tagName === 'IMG') return element.src;
  if (element.tagName === 'P') return element.innerHTML;
  return '';
})
```

Comment: can you post an example of the contents of `textData` after you run your code?

Comment: Hello there was an error due to a typo in your code, otherwise this is correct. That is why it didn't work at first. You have two L's in HTML. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You can map the element array like below:

```js
const textData = Array
  .from(document.querySelectorAll('.product-image, .product-detail > p'))
  .map(element => {
    if (element.tagName === 'IMG') return element.src
    if (element.tagName === 'P') return element.innerHTML
    return null
  })
```

If you want filter null in the array:

```js
const textData = Array
  .from(document.querySelectorAll('.product-image, .product-detail > p'))
  .map(element => {
    if (element.tagName === 'IMG') return element.src
    if (element.tagName === 'P') return element.innerHTML
    return null
  })
  .filter(item => item !== null)
```

Below is the example of above code:

[image: example of above code]

It is exactly excuted beyond console panel in devtools of the current page: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60461491

Comment: same result and code basically as the first : [ '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '' ]

Comment: Just try excute `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.product-image, .product-detail > p'))` to see what will you get?

Comment: Hello this code does work for me, Thanks for the submission, I would mark this as the correct answer but the other user posted first.

Comment: It's ok. But you need to know, I didn't down vote down this question.

Comment: @TrevorO'Farrell at least mark the answer as useful.

Comment: I cannot, I don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: I would if I could